# Firestore SetOptions.mergeFields() not working as expected using POJO

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a specific field in a document using POJO, as written in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SetOptions). I could use `SetOptions.mergeFields()`. But it's updating other fields with null instead of keeping the other fields (which excluded from mergeFields) untouched. Is it intended?

Here is my code :

```
UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
userModel.setStatus(0);
setTask = documentReferenceToUse.set(userModel, SetOptions.mergeFields("status"));

setTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
    {
        if (!emitter.isDisposed())
        {
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
    {
        if (!emitter.isDisposed())
        {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    }
});
```

And here is my document structure :
[image: document structure]

[Solved]
Turned out the issue came from my Firebase wrapper code. So there is no actual problem on the Firebase SDL side.

Comment: Please add the code you are using and your database structure.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** After taking another closer look at your code, I found that you need to change this line of code:

```
setTask = documentReferenceToUse.set(model, SetOptions.mergeFields("status"));
```

with:

```
setTask = documentReferenceToUse.set(userModel, SetOptions.mergeFields("status"));
```

You are passing as the first argument, not the object that you have just created but another one. So, the correct object that must be used is: `userModel`.

You can also use another approach, by getting that entire object from the database. Having the object, you can use setters to change the value of the fileds beneath it. After you have used the setters, you can use `set()` method directly on the reference to add the object the database.

```
documentReferenceToUse.set(userModelFromDatabase);
```

You can also use a `Map` in order to make an update:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("status", 0);
documentReferenceToUse.update(map);
```

Comment: The new object of UserModel is intended since I want to update only specific fields of the UserModel.

Comment: Your suggestion is for sure would work, but I heavily wrapped the Firebase SDK so I can switch to other service easily if needed.

Comment: If we cannot update specific fields using objects then there is no point to use SetOptions.mergeFields(), and it contradicting the doc since it said mergeFields works with both `Map` and `Object`. I'm writing a ticket to Firebase team about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that's not answering my question. The `model` was simply just a typo, it should be `userModel` indeed (updated), and it still has the issue anyway.

IMHO, based on the doc, whether we're using new object or the object we fetched from DB, it should behave the same since we only wanted to update certain field on the DB.

Comment: Have you received an answer from Firebase team?

Comment: Yes, it's working as expected on their side. After checking multiple time on my code, turned out the issue came from my Firebase wrapper. So, the the issue is actually on my code instead of the Firebase SDK. Thanks for your help Alex.